# How to decode signature pars with js file in php

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, youtube

How do I decode YouTube video signature with this `base.js url` in php

I want to parse this signature with this JavaScript in PHP

https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflF6iOW5/base.js

`1. Original signature`
`558D58CA687B9BD6B4C7E22FDB1C07395679C758489.0203EF29F3E3BD1E7A32567C9F02FE09035C837676`

2 .after Parse out put decode signature
`858CA687B95D6B4C7E22FDB1C07395679C75D489.0203EF29F3E3BD1E7A32567C9F02FE09035C738`

how do I parse this signature with JS in PHP and get 2nd decode signature

Comment: Do you have several accounts and try to boost your rep with?

Comment: i have old account but i removed my old account

Comment: Maybe this helps ;-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510857/best-approach-to-decode-youtube-cipher-signature-using-php-or-js

Comment: @brandelizer thanks for reply sir but how can i add this in php