# Decoding youtube base.js cipher 2016

Tags: javascript, php, youtube

I am writing a js+php software to make downloading of youtube videos much easier, but I encountered a following problem:

I get informations about video this way:

`parse_str(file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=".$id),$info);`

Now some of the videos returns: `use_cipher_signature => True`, which i would like to bypass.

I've searched trouch the Web, but all i got was some posts from 2014.
(this one contains good introduction to topic: [Best approach to decode Youtube cipher signature using PHP or JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510857/best-approach-to-decode-youtube-cipher-signature-using-php-or-js))

I know that i have to look at source of `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cipheredID`, extract *base.js script and then find deciphering code in it, but *base.js is too much obfuscated for me.

Is there anyone who can help me?

And second question:
Does algorithm od encoding/decoding signatures depends on location? Beceause mine is pl_PL(https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/player-pl_PL-vfluAB5bv/base.js)
and for example US users will have different link en_US

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to extract the base.js file from a youTube link ?

Comment: Yes, I know. I dont know how to extract deciphering function from it

Comment: Can you share the method ?
I can see the file when I open the YouTube link and look at the source code, but I believe there is an easy way to get the file directly.

Comment: something like this in php: `$ytPlayerCode=file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$id);
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 $dom->loadHTML($ytPlayerCode);
 foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $node)
 {
  if(strpos($node->getAttribute("src"), ".js") != false){
   echo htmlspecialchars($node->nodeValue.': '.$node->getAttribute("src"))."<br>";
  }
 }`